# JQuery Datepicker, angularJs date issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive, momentjs

I have date in JSON format which I am getting from MVC WEB API Controller (2013-09-17 15:18:53Z).
I am using jquery datepicker with angularjs. I have input element in which I need to show date based on culture, but on saving time I need it again in JSON format.

Currenlty I am facing an issue of invalid. Can you please suggest the best way to handle it in the directive.

ServerSide : WebAPI

```
public class MyModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
}


[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public MyModel GetInfo(int id)
{
    MyModel model = GetInfo(id);     
    return model;
}

public static MyModel GetInfo (int id)
{
    MyModel model = new model();
    model.Id = id;
        model.MyDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Client Side :

Directive Jquery DatePicker :

```
angular.module('common').directive('datePicker', function ($locale) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

      $(function () {
        element.datepicker({
          onSelect: function (date) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

UI :

```
<input type="text" name="Mydate" data-ng-model="vm.data.MyDate" date-picker />
```

On Service Loaded :

```
 myService.getInfo(id)
         .then(
         function (load) {
           vm.data = load.data;

           vm.data.Mydate = $filter('date')(load.data.MyDate, 'shortDate');
         });
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Why to use jQuery controls while doing Angularjs? Try using a better datepicker like this one : https://github.com/jkuri/ngDatepicker

Comment: I widely use Jquery control in the application so I don't want any additional library to be added. Thats the reason. For each issue new library is not the right solution for the project.

Comment: I have added code in the question section

Answer (score 1):

Why use the jQuery controls while mainly working in AngularJS? Consider using  [AngularJS's stock datepicker](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker).

The [3rd-party ngDatepicker](https://github.com/jkuri/ngDatepicker) as suggested in the comments hasn't been updated for many years, the demo is dead, and the code is likely incompatible with the modern AngularJS.

You can find examples and a live demo of the AngularJS's official datepicker at the link provided.